# Hitachi Disk Fitness Test doesn't allow any keyboard use

Tags: hard-drive, hard-drive-recovery

Has anyone tried to use the Hitachi Disk Fitness Test v4.16?

I magaged to download it and make a bootable CD.

I boot with the CD and get to the main/first "continue/cancel" page.

I can't move the mouse or use the keyboard so I can't continue or pick anything.

(Normally, my keyboard and mouse work fine in Windows XP.)

Answer (score 0):

Are they USB devices? You may need to enable USB support in the BIOS for legacy devices before using the keyboard. Not sure about mouse support.

Comment: Wired USB keyboard.  Wireless USB mouse.  They both work 100% fine.  Should I still need to "enable them" in BIOS?

Comment: Are they enabled in the BIOS? If not, they need to be.